# Program only reading first row of Matrix in C

Tags: c, file, matrix

I am trying to read in a 3x3 matrix from a file. The file contains data that looks like this.

```
5 65 3
3 11 15
22 8 3
```

So far I have the following code,

```
int data[3][3];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
FILE *fptr = fopen("data.txt", "r");

for(; i < 3; ++i){
    fscanf(fptr, "%d %d %d", &(data[i][0]), &(data[i][1]), &(data[i][2]));
}
i = 0;

for(; i < 3; ++i){
    for(; j < 3; ++j){
        printf("%d ", data[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

fclose(fptr);
```

However, only the first line of the matrix is read from the file. When I try printing only the first line is shown followed by two empty lines.

Comment: why don't you initialize `j=0` in the inner loop?

Comment: Your program code isn't complete and you don't include the output of your program.  This means you're missing a complete, verifiable example.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: i initialized it in the first line

Comment: I would second @Jean-FrançoisFabre's suggestion.  Though what you're doing works, it's prone to errors when you forget to reinitialize.  Not only does it cut down on lines, it makes the program a lot clearer, and in the case of a reused counter variable, such as `i` in this case, a lot less prone to bugs ( I realize you reinitialize it in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just write for loops properly:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
    for(j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
```

Else, in your case, even if outer loop is ok but inner `j` loop runs once properly, but since `j==3` and isn't reset, it doesn't resume for the next 2 outer iterations.

The 2 last `i` loops run empty and do nothing.

(and it's not necessary to initialize `i` and `j` outside the `for` statements)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below given lines to read the first line of the file & then store the number by separating them.

```
fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]", c);
```

Refer this link for more details

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this pretty easily. Modify these lines and add in the newline character.

```
for(; i < 3; ++i){
    fscanf(fptr, "%d %d %d\n", &(data[i][0]), &(data[i][1]), &(data[i][2]));
}
```